# C function pointer parameter printing issue

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I have the following code:

```
struct cache_t *                /* pointer to cache created */
cache_create(char *name,        /* name of the cache */
             int nsets,         /* total number of sets in cache */
             int bsize,         /* block (line) size of cache */
             int balloc,        /* allocate data space for blocks? */
             int usize,         /* size of user data to alloc w/blks */
             int assoc,         /* associativity of cache */
             enum cache_policy policy,  /* replacement policy w/in sets */
             /* block access function, see description w/in struct cache def */
             unsigned int (*blk_access_fn) (enum mem_cmd cmd,
                                            md_addr_t baddr, int bsize,
                                            struct cache_blk_t * blk,
                                            tick_t now,
                                            int context_id),
             unsigned int hit_latency)
{                               /* latency in cycles for a hit */
    struct cache_t *cp;
    struct cache_blk_t *blk;
    int i, j, bindex;
----
----
---

  cp->blk_access_fn = blk_access_fn;

----
---
```

**I WANT TO PRINT context_id and baddr . HOW CAN I DO IT ?** 
I have tried typecasting and everything but it keeps giving me error:
symbol "context_id" is invalid in current context.
HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED.

Comment: You can always indent `C` code with `indent -kr` command in linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the `cache_create` function. It doesn't have `context_id` or `baddr` parameters at all. What it does have as a parameter is `blk_access_fn` which is a **function pointer**. That function which is presumably called by `cache_create` and **it** would have those 2 variables as parameters.

A way to better visualize this would be like so:

```
typedef unsigned int (*blk_access_fn_ptr)(enum mem_cmd cmd, md_addr_t baddr, int bsize, struct cache_blk_t *blk, tick_t now, int context_id);

struct cache_t *            /* pointer to cache created */
cache_create(char *name,        /* name of the cache */
     int nsets,         /* total number of sets in cache */
     int bsize,         /* block (line) size of cache */
     int balloc,        /* allocate data space for blocks? */
     int usize,         /* size of user data to alloc w/blks */
     int assoc,         /* associativity of cache */
     enum cache_policy policy,  /* replacement policy w/in sets */
     /* block access function, see description w/in struct cache def */
     blk_access_fn_ptr blk_access_fn,
     unsigned int hit_latency)  /* latency in cycles for a hit */
{
    ...
}
```

This code is **identical** in functionality to the code you posted. As you can see, `cache_create` doesn't have the parameters you are looking for at all. You must pass a function with an appropriate prototype as the `blk_access_fn` parameter, and it will have them.

Comment: This is how it should be defined. Didn't know the definition provided by OP works. :o

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understood what you meant however I am still finding it difficult that how can i then print the fn blk_access_fn_ptr values for baddr and context_id ? Consider that a function a (same parameters) like the prototype.

Comment: @user1908559: like I said, you need to pass a function to `cache_create` which has the appropriate prototype, when **that** function is called, you should be able to print its parameters with no issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did work.. will let you know if i need any more help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you aren't passing in context_id, you are taking in a fxn pointer that takes an argument of context_id.  You can have access to them inside of blk_access_fn, but not inside of cache_create.